# Receing 'JwtSecurityToken' does not support 'SamlAssertionKeyIdentifierClause' creation.' error while creating channel with issued token in WCF 4.5

Tags: c#, wcf, jwt, wif, ws-federation

When trying to generate Custom STS token with 'JwtSecurityToken', received following error message:

**System.NotSupportedException: ''JwtSecurityToken' does not support 'SamlAssertionKeyIdentifierClause' creation.'**

I'm using .NET/WCF/WIF 4.5

JwtSecurityTokenHandler is from

System.IdentityModel.Tokens.Jwt, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35

Any help is highly appreciated.

The stack trace is as follows:

Server stack trace: 
   at System.IdentityModel.Tokens.SecurityToken.CreateKeyIdentifierClauseT
   at System.ServiceModel.Security.Tokens.SecurityTokenParameters.CreateKeyIdentifierClause[TExternalClause,TInternalClause](SecurityToken token, SecurityTokenReferenceStyle referenceStyle)
   at System.ServiceModel.Security.SendSecurityHeader.SignWithSupportingTokens()
   at System.ServiceModel.Security.SendSecurityHeader.CompleteSecurityApplication()
   at System.ServiceModel.Security.SecurityAppliedMessage.OnWriteMessage(XmlDictionaryWriter writer)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.BufferedMessageWriter.WriteMessage(Message message, BufferManager bufferManager, Int32 initialOffset, Int32 maxSizeQuota)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.TextMessageEncoderFactory.TextMessageEncoder.WriteMessage(Message message, Int32 maxMessageSize, BufferManager bufferManager, Int32 messageOffset)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.HttpOutput.SerializeBufferedMessage(Message message, Boolean shouldRecycleBuffer)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.HttpOutput.Send(TimeSpan timeout)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.HttpChannelFactory`1.HttpRequestChannel.HttpChannelRequest.SendRequest(Message message, TimeSpan timeout)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.RequestChannel.Request(Message message, TimeSpan timeout)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.SecurityChannelFactory`1.SecurityRequestChannel.Request(Message message, TimeSpan timeout)
   at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.RequestChannelBinder.Request(Message message, TimeSpan timeout)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannel.Call(String action, Boolean oneway, ProxyOperationRuntime operation, Object[] ins, Object[] outs, TimeSpan timeout)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannelProxy.InvokeService(IMethodCallMessage methodCall, ProxyOperationRuntime operation)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannelProxy.Invoke(IMessage message)

```
WS2007FederationHttpBinding ws2007FederationHttpBinding = CreateStsBinding();
        RequestSecurityToken request = new RequestSecurityToken
        {
            RequestType = RequestTypes.Issue,
            AppliesTo = new EndpointReference("appliestoURLGoeshere"),
            KeyType = KeyTypes.Symmetric,
            TokenType = "urn:ietf:params:oauth:token-type:jwt"
    };

        EndpointIdentity rpIdentity = new X509CertificateEndpointIdentity(new X509Certificate2(Convert.FromBase64String("base64CertificateValues")));
        WSTrustChannelFactory factory = new WSTrustChannelFactory(ws2007FederationHttpBinding, new EndpointAddress(new Uri("endpointUri"), rpIdentity))
        {
            TrustVersion = TrustVersion.WSTrust13
        };
        factory.Credentials.SupportInteractive = false;
        factory.Credentials.UseIdentityConfiguration = true;
        factory.Credentials.ServiceCertificate.Authentication.CertificateValidationMode = X509CertificateValidationMode.None;
        factory.Credentials.ServiceCertificate.Authentication.RevocationMode = X509RevocationMode.NoCheck;
        IWSTrustChannelContract channel = factory.CreateChannelWithIssuedToken(myJwtIssuedToken);       
         //...............Receive error here............
         SecurityToken securityToken = channel.Issue(request);
        return securityToken;
```

Comment: I see this question is quite old but have you found any solution to this error?